# Transit visa requirement for Indian citizen in Turkey

Tags: visas, transit, airports, turkey

I’m travelling to Canada as an international student from India. The flight I have booked has a layover at Istanbul airport of few hours and then I will catch my next flight. Do i need a transit visa for that?